# TypeError: QPixmap.toImage(): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QPixmap'

Tags: python, pyqt, qimage, qpixmap

I have a method that compare labels contents and return matches . The method is :

```
def get_selected_image(self):
    if self.labelDisplayBigImage.pixmap() is None:
        return False
    first_image = QtGui.QPixmap.toImage(self.labelDisplayBigImage.pixmap())
    selectable_images = [self.labelDisplayImage1, self.labelDisplayImage2, self.labelDisplayImage3,
                         self.labelDisplayImage4, self.labelDisplayImage5, self.labelDisplayImage6,
                         self.labelDisplayImage7, self.labelDisplayImage8]

    for i in range(len(selectable_images)):
        second_image = QtGui.QPixmap.toImage(selectable_images[i].pixmap())
        if first_image == second_image:
            return selectable_images[i].pixmap()
```

But got an error `TypeError: QPixmap.toImage(): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QPixmap'` . So what is the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

To use the "toImage" method you first have to instantiate the Qpixmap class to an object. See http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/QPixmap-loadFromData-td5003372.html

In the example "loadfromdata" is used instead of "toImage", but the principle is the same.

Comment: You mean like this : `second_image = QtGui.QPixmap() second_image.toImage(selectable_images[i].pixmap())` . I have tried this but got an error `QPixmap.toImage() : too many arguments`

Answer (score 0):

The `xxx.pixmap()` methods you are using already return constructed `QPixmap`s. Instead of trying to use the `QPixmap.toImage(xxx.pixmap())`, just use `xxx.pixmap().toImage()`.

In your case that would be `self.labelDisplayBigImage.pixmap().toImage()` and `selectable_images[i].pixmap().toImage()`.

Comment: At this time got an error : `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'toImage'`

Comment: @CahitYıldırım Then `selectable_images[i].pixmap()` is returning `None` for one or more of your images. You'll have to debug that yourself.